# fieldset in firefox page zoom

Tags: html, firefox

i have a fieldset in a form. when i use firefox and i ctrl+middle mouse button to zoom with mouse pointer inside the fieldset, nothing is happening. it works in IE/chrome. replacing fieldset with div works in firefox.

am i using fieldset wrong? or is my firefox broken?

```
    <form name="test">
        <fieldset>
            <label>test</label>
            <input />
            <label>test</label>
            <input />
        </fieldset>
        <div style="width:1000px;border:1px solid black;">
            <label>test</label>
            <input />
            <label>test</label>
            <input />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It's working for my Firefox 44.0.2 up to date. https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NTEwODAzXzI2OTY4MzU Do you use a CMS like Drupal?

Comment: @zer00ne make sure your mouse is inside the fieldset and try to ctrl+middle mouse button. because ive tested on both my computers and i run 44.0.2 as well and its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some digging and found the **[bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343945)** that describes exactly what you are experiencing. It's 9 years old, so I wouldn't hold your breath for it being fixed anytime soon.

Comment: hey absolutely amazing for taking the time to check and respond. at first i thought i wasnt using fieldset properly. but this is good. thanks and gave a nice day!

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking the time in giving a thoughtful question. You have a great day as well, sir.